# Netlogo: Assign variable using probabilities

Tags: list, variables, random, probability, netlogo

How to assign a string or integer variable to turtle, using probabilities of the variables in a group/list? For example it is 0.4 probability that one specific variable is used from specific group/list. The function selects randomly the variable based on probability. I need to use the same method afterwards to choose a variable (string) from a list according to probability.
In python it should be:

```
import random
def random_value(probability_list, values):
    r = random.random()
    index = 0
    while(r >= 0 and index < len(probability_list)):
      r -= probability_list[index]
      index += 1
    value=values[index - 1]
    value_index=index-1
    return value,value_index
```

I tried it in Netlogo like below (get error that index is -1) but is there a better way?

```
globals [random_nr probabilities some_list index]
to initialize-variables
  set some_list[]
  set probabilities[]
end
to random_pick
  set random_nr random-float 1
  set probabilities [0.1 0.2 0.4 0.3]
  set some_list ["String1" "String2" "String3" "String4"]
  set index 0
  while [(random_nr >= 0) and (length probabilities < index)] [
   set random_nr random_nr - item index probabilities
   set index index + 1 ]
  set index index - 1
end
```

Comment: Some general advice: if you find yourself messing with indexes and while loops, you're probably doing it wrong; there is almost always a better, more NetLogo-ish, way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there a better way?

Yes there is.

NetLogo 6.0 comes with the [`rnd` extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/rnd.html) bundled. (You can also [download the extension separately](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension/releases/tag/v2.0.0) for earlier versions of NetLogo.)

The `rnd` extension offers the [`rnd:weighted-one-of-list`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/rnd.html#rnd:weighted-one-of-list) primitive, which does exactly what you're trying to do:

```
extensions [ rnd ]

to-report pick
  let probabilities [0.1 0.2 0.4 0.3]
  let some_list ["String1" "String2" "String3" "String4"]
  report first rnd:weighted-one-of-list (map list some_list probabilities) last
end
```

Let me unpack the last expression a bit:

- The role of `(map list some_list probabilities)` is to "zip" the two lists together, in order to get a list of pairs of the form: `[["String1" 0.1] ["String2" 0.2] ["String3" 0.4] ["String4" 0.3]]`.
- That list of pairs is passed as the first argument to `rnd:weighted-one-of-list`. We pass `last` as the second argument of `rnd:weighted-one-of-list` to tell it that it should use the second item of each pair as the probability.
- `rnd:weighted-one-of-list` then picks one of the pairs at random, and returns that whole pair. But since we're only interested in the first item of the pair, we use `first` to extract it.

To understand how that code works, it helps to understand how [Anonymous procedures](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#anonymous-procedures) work. Note how we make use of the concise syntax for passing `list` to `map` and for passing `last` to `rnd:weighted-one-of-list`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't overlook the `rnd` extension:
https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension 
But it is possible to do it essentially as you propose.  I'll to that here, but it would be better to use explicit arguments.

```
to-report random-pick
  let _r random-float 1
  let _ps [0.1 0.2 0.4 0.3]
  let _lst ["String1" "String2" "String3" "String4"]
  let _i 0
  while [_r >= item _i _ps] [
   set _r (_r - item _i _ps)
   set _i (_i + 1) ]
  report item _i _lst
end
```