# NETLOGO - Option with a certain probability

Tags: probability, netlogo, patch

I try to make my first ABM using NETLOGO. I would like to show in an easy way how an election works.

So I create 3 types of turtles : young people, adults and senior (I create this because of candidate's preferences are not the same, one's are more social than others more liberal...).

So I would like to make them move, and changing the p-color of the patch into they move with probability. 
For example in 2012 young people vote (in a simply way) 30% social (color 136), 30% liberal (color 97), 20% extreme-right (color 104) and 10% extreme-left (red).

So, I would like in my code to introduce probability when turtles move to patches and change color.

This is the interesting part of my code :

```
to chose-color-young

ask jeunes

[if pcolor = white [set pcolor one-of [136 97 104 15]]]

end
```

I would like to do something like that 136 with probability = 0.3 ;97 with probability = 0.3 ; 104 with probability = 0.20 and 15 with probability = 0.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netlogo: Assign variable using probabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901313/netlogo-assign-variable-using-probabilities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`rnd` extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/rnd.html) does exactly what you need:

```
let probs [[136 0.3] [97 0.3] [104 0.20] [15 0.10]]
ask jeunes [
  if pcolor = white [
    set pcolor first rnd:weighted-one-of-list probs last
  ]
]
```

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41902311/487946) for more explanations on the `rnd` extension.